# android: what is the onCreate equivalent in unity script?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, deep-linking

I have a unity app that should run on android. I have some native code (inside a plugin) that I need to call in order to process deep-link activation of the app, and I need to call it from my unity script when the app gets reopened by that deep link. Where is the appropriate place to make that call?

Note OnApplicationPause is not a good option, since it mimics onResume, and you MUST NOT process deep links inside onResume on Android because it will cause them to get re-processed over and over every time the app is reopened after the initial click on the deep link.

So basically, I am looking for a lifecycle-equivalent to onCreate, but in unity script (I do not have legal permissions to replace the native unity activity in this case and simply override its onCreate method).

Answer (score 0):

onCreate() is run basically on the initialization of any activity. It's kind of hard to think about it in terms of Unity3D. When you call a level the Start() and Awake() are called, the latter first. You could potentially UnitySendMessage() from your native plugin on the java Android side. I believe the syntax looks like:

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObjectName1", "MethodName1", "Message to send");
```

And inside your GameObjectName1 construct MethodName1 method with string params passed:

```
function void MethodName1 (message:String) {}
```

Not sure if this will suffice for your needs. I've done comparable with iOS, i'm sure there should be an Android equivalent with Unity3D.